# Android Font family CSS

Tags: android, html, css, fonts

I am loading different fonted texts to into HTML display. I want two font styles to be loaded .

```
  file:///android_asset/fonts/mm2.ttf
  file:///android_asset/fonts/mm3.ttf
```

I can call only one font to be appeared. mm2 is OK but How to set mm3,mm2 as family ? Here is my code.

```
private static final String CSS_mm= "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face{font-family: mm;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/mm2.ttf\"), url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/mm3.ttf\") } body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,div,p,input,textarea {font-family:mm;font-weight: normal;font-style: normal; font-size:18px; } p { line-height: 200%;}</style>";
```

Call it from method by . (It is just a brief with few important variables and lines.)

```
html = new StringBuilder(CSS).append(FONTSIZE_START).append(fontsize).append(FONTSIZE_MIDDLE).append(abstractText).append(CSS_mm).append(FONTSIZE_END).toString();
```

mm3 Fonted texts are not correct and appeared as mm2(i think), Please kindly suggest me . I am new to css/html language. Thank you for interesting my problem.

Comment: Can you post an example of what the resulting html looks like? Preferably as a stacksnippet.